# property does not exists on type Object from subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, jslint

Im using a forkJoin to do multiple http calls but it give me the error  `error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'`

```
forkJoin(this.userservice.getUser(), this.userservice.getDashboard()).pipe(
    map(([userData, dashboardData]) => {

      // set the user
      this.user = userData;

      // set order count
      this.orderCount.new = dashboardData.data.new.length;
      console.log(dashboardData);

      this.dataLoaded = true;
    })
).subscribe();
```

I understand the error because this property comes from a external api so in angular/ionic it is not set. but when i set for example

```
map(([userData, dashboardData<any>]) => {
```

or something like that, it does not work. How can i fix this?

the getUser en getDashboard return http objects

```
    getUser() {
    return this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + '/auth/user').pipe(
        map(results => {
            console.log(results);
            return results;
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: try this `this.orderCount.new = (dashboardData as any).data.new.length;`

Comment: thanks...let me add it as  answer!

Comment: Did you try actually specifying a generic type for the response per the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, replace this line

```
  this.orderCount.new = dashboardData.data.new.length;
```

with this

```
  this.orderCount.new = (dashboardData as any).data.new.length;
```

What this line does is cast the Object into typescript's any type.

A better way would be to create model classes for data and uses those model class instead of any.

Answer (score 2):

you can type the array like this:

```
map(([userData, dashboardData]: [UserData, DashboardData]) =>
```

or you can just type your observables. don't abuse any.